# Delete MySql Records older than a half hour or 1800 seconds?

Tags: mysql

The current MYSQL Is

```
DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `expires` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Not sure how i would make it do what i want to do. I was thinking of using php and doing unixtime-1800 and then using that in the MySQL, which would be okay for my app. Not sure if you can do it all in MySQL becuase i'm just wondering.

The PHP i had would be somthing like this

```
<?Php
$time = time() - 1800;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `expires` < $time;")
?>
```

Comment: What expires column contains? Is it date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just substract the number of seconds you want

```
DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `expires` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1800);
```

How often do you plan on running this query ?

Comment: every 10 mins i was thinking.

Comment: So the `sessions` column is supposed to never get above... 1000 rows?

Comment: It could... I mean we will only have a few members but if it grows, i guess we will be in trouble?  Not sure what a work around would be.

Comment: Well depending when you store data (guessing on each pageview). You're fine if you have aproximately 1 user / second

Comment: yeah. I updated some of the code so if the user uses the site and if their own session expires, it will act like they never logged in. So i could really run this script ever hour, half hour, 24 hours, so i don't want to grow a REALLY Big database for people who came to the site and never came back.

Comment: Have you consider using $_SESSION and [cache expire](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php) ?

Comment: No. Someone told me to use ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'none'); because i'm serving CSS files from php also, something about it causing more load then needed. But i think what i'm doing now will work.

Comment: I am using $_SESSION. I'm using session_set_save_handler to override the built in methods. Making it use SQL and not File System. So the website can run on multiple servers if i wanted to. At first the site will be small but later as it grows, i plan to get more web servers.

Comment: Then going to use a NFS for images also. So this project i'm working on is designed to run one a single server or millions of servers if needed.

Comment: You should consider using [code igniter session](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). I have found them to be rather flexible.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I'm not using Code Igniter nor do i want to. I been working on my own Framework for about a year on and off. So my own kinda way of doing everything :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do :

```
DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `expires` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1800);
```

Answer (score 0):

That approach will cause huge performance degradations on the high-loaded system. The very first proposal is to create a new table every half an hour and flush older tables by some logic.

Edit: OK, maybe not so huge degradations with half-an-hour GC, but it's a bad design generally.